# Autoprefix for linear gradient using scss and codekit not working

Tags: css, sass, codekit

Hello I am using sass and compiling with codekit. Codekits "run autoprefixer on the css file" is checked so it claims to be running an autoprefixer while compiling but it does not seem to add the prefixes for each browser

Here is the sass (scss)

```
$purpgradient: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0,1,29) 0%, rgb(23,1,58) 53%, rgb(45,1,86) 100%);

body {
  background-image: $purpgradient;
}
```

and the output:

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00011d 0%, #17013a 53%, #2d0156 100%);
}
```

seems to not of added the prefixes at all. am I making some type of error

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the autoprefixer ran through the code before the scss compiled. Try it without the variable.

Comment: hmm i removed the variable and am still not getting the autoprefixes

Comment: i think that linear gradient now works on all browsers and it doesnt need to be auto prefixed. seems like codekit is smart enough to recognize that

Comment: Then double check the settings (which browsers are targeted) and verify the autoprefixer runs by testing it with another attribute (display: flex, user-select...). You can check https://autoprefixer.github.io/ to check what should come out.

Comment: i tested it with another attribute and it is working. seems like linear graqdient doesnt need to be autoprefixed

Comment: Then you should check which browser versions are configured and adjust to your needs